# errors using unix('who') in matlab

Tags: matlab, unix

My matlab can't recognise the unix('who'); it returns as

> the 'who' is not an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

and other unix-like command also cannot run either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are on a Windows machine. Try some windows commands with system. like system('dir').

Comment: so my understanding is that matlab just passes the command you type to OS terminal, run the command and return the result. If you are on a windows machine, this command 'who' is not recognized as it is a unix-like command.

Comment: Yes,my system is win7,but on the other machine with the same system, the command can run normally. I need solve it because of I'm running projects that has a mount of unix-like commands.

Comment: do you have cygwin or any other linux emulator installed on the other system? because apparently who executable is on the system path on this system.

Comment: could you check the location of who on this system by doing           "cd \" and "dir /s /b who"

Comment: yes,with cygwin and correct system path, it works. Thank you!

Comment: Windows 7 also has something called SUA - subsystem for unix applications